# Trying to get a string concatenated in Linq2Entities query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create a `Dictionary<string, string>` from the combined results of two string fields in an entity.

I am using this dictionary to populate a drop down list. For this particular case, both the key and value are the same.

Here is the query I have so far:

```
var qry = (
    from x in db.Treatment_Type
    select new { 
        TreatmentCode = x.Project_Classification + ":" + x.Improvement_Type
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToDictionary<string, string>(x => x);
```

I am trying to concatenate the `Project_Classification` and `Improvement_Type` values into one value. It is coming back as an anonymous type, instead of a string, so I get errors about how the dictionary can't infer the types from the anonymous type and advising me to explicitly state the type. When I do that, I get errors that anonymous types can't be converted to string.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just get rid of it being an anonymous type? That's not helping you:

```
var qry = (from x in db.Treatment_Type
           select x.Project_Classification + ":" + x.Improvement_Type)
          .AsEnumerable()
          .ToDictionary<string, string>(x => x);
```

Only use anonymous types when you actually get some benefit from it :)

The same applies to query expressions - in this case I'd use:

```
var qry = db.Treatment_Type
            .Select(x => x.Project_Classification + ":" + x.Improvement_Type)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToDictionary<string, string>(x => x);
```

Comment: Doh...  it's late on a Friday... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var qry = (from x in db.Treatment_Type
                           select new { TreatmentCode = x.Project_Classification + ":" + x.Improvement_Type }).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<string, string>(x => x);
```

It's coming back as an anonymous type because you are using anonymous type annotation. which is. new {//some stuff}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var qry = (from x in db.Treatment_Type
select x.Project_Classification + ":" + x.Improvement_Type ).ToDictionary<string, string>(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this `ToDictionary<string, string>(x => x);` into this ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);

And i'm guessing that this two "Project_Classification" and "Improvement_Type" values are string Types.